# How can change in cost function be positive?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, optimization, gradient-descent, loss-functions

In [chapter 1 of Nielsen's Neural Networks and Deep Learning](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html) it says

> To make gradient descent work correctly, we need to choose the learning rate η to be small enough that Equation (9) is a good approximation. **If we don't, we might end up with $\Delta C>0$, which obviously would not be good!** At the same time, we don't want $\eta$ to be too small, since that will make the changes $\Delta v$ tiny, and thus the gradient descent algorithm will work very slowly. In practical implementations, $\eta$ is often varied so that Equation (9) remains a good approximation, but the algorithm isn't too slow. We'll see later how this works.

But just a few paragraphs before we established that $\Delta C\approx−\eta\nabla C⋅\nabla C=−\eta\|\nabla C\|^2$ is obviously always negative (for positive $\eta$). So how can $\Delta C$ be positive if we don't choose a *small enough* learning rate? What is meant there?

Comment: Because it relies on an approximation. You take the gradient with respect to C at a point v1 (i.e, immediate rate of change in C when at v1). So it only makes sense to multiply it by very small change in v1 (in other words, in a very tiny neighborhood of v1). If the change is too big, then the approx does not work anymore as it would not be sensible to think that the rate of change remains the same over that neighborhood.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the learning rate is too large, you can "overshoot". Imagine you're using gradient descent to minimize a 1-dimensional, convex parabola. If you take a *small enough* step, you'll end up closer to the minimum than you were before. But if you take *too large* a step, you'll end up on the opposite side of the parabola, possibly even farther away from the minimum than you were before!

Here's a simple demonstration: $f(x)=x^2$ achieves a minimum at $x=0$; $f^\prime(x)=2x$, so our gradient update has the form
$$
\begin{align}
x^{(t+1)} &= x^{(t)} - \eta ~ f^\prime \left( x^{(t)} \right)\\
&= x^{(t)} - 2 \eta x^{(t)}\\
&= x^{(t)}(1 - 2 \eta)
\end{align}
$$

If we start at $x^{(0)}=-1$, we can plot the progress of the optimizer and for $\eta = 0.1$, it's not hard to see that we are slowly but surely approaching the minimum.
[image]

If we start from $x^{(0)}=-1$ but choose $\eta = 1.125$ instead, then the optimizer diverges. Instead of becoming closer to the minimum at each iteration, the optimizer will always over shoot; obviously, the change in the objective function is positive at each step.

[image]

Why does it overshoot? Because the the step size $\eta$ is so large that the linear approximation to the loss is not a *good* approximation. That's what Nielsen means when he writes

> To make gradient descent work correctly, we need to choose the learning rate $\eta$ to be small enough that Equation (9) is a good approximation.

Stated another way, if $\Delta C > 0$, then Equation (9) is not a good approximation; you'll need to select a smaller value for $\eta$.

For the starting point $x^{(0)}=-1$, the dividing line between these two regimes is $\eta=1.0$; at this value of $\eta$, the optimizer alternates between $-1$ for even iterations and and $1$ for odd iterations. For $\eta < 1$, gradient descent converges from this starting point; for $\eta > 1$, gradient descent diverges.

Some information about how to choose good learning rates for quadratic functions can be found in my answer to [Why are second-order derivatives useful in convex optimization?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145323/why-are-second-order-derivatives-useful-in-convex-optimization/145329#145329)

---

```
f <- function(x) x^2
grad_x <- function(x) 2*x
descent <- function(x0, N, gradient, eta=0.1){
    x_traj <- numeric(N)
    x_traj[1] <- x0
    for(i in 2:N){
        nabla_x_i <- grad_x(x_traj[i - 1])
        x_traj[i] <- x_traj[i - 1] - eta * nabla_x_i
    }
    return(x_traj)
} 

x <- seq(-2,2,length.out=1000)

x_traj_eta_01 <- descent(x0=-1.0, N=10, gradient=grad_x, eta=0.1)

png("gd_eta_0.1.png")
plot(x,f(x), type="l", sub=expression(paste(eta, "=0.1")), main="Gradient descent for f(x)=x * x")
lines(x_traj_eta_01, f(x_traj_eta_01), type="o", col="red", lwd=2)
dev.off()

png("gd_eta_1.125.png")
x_traj_eta_1125 <- descent(x0=-1.0, N=20, gradient=grad_x, eta=1.125)
plot(x,f(x), type="l", sub=expression(paste(eta, "=1.125")), main="Gradient descent for f(x)=x * x")
lines(x_traj_eta_1125, f(x_traj_eta_1125), type="o", col="red", lwd=2)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Intuitively I understand perfectly what you're saying, I've been through this in introductory machine learning courses. But now that I'm taking a closer look at the math, it's not adding up. Note that $ΔC≈−η‖∇C‖^2$ (see the book chapter I mentioned for the full reasoning) is algebraically *always* negative for positive learning rate $η$. So how could it ever be positive as the paragraph I quoted seems to suggest? Your reply doesn't answer this perspective. I think the comment by Tom might be on the right track, I'm carefully considering it right now.

Comment: I think you're being mislead by the $\approx$ symbol. Even for simple, convex problems (like a convex quadratic in 1 dimension) it is absolutely true that for $\eta$ sufficiently large, the change can be **positive**. That's why the text says "To make gradient descent work correctly, we need to choose the learning rate $\eta$ to be small enough that Equation (9) is a good approximation." The $\approx$ symbol is used instead of the $=$ symbol because the approximation is not *always* correct, but instead is only correct for $\eta$ sufficiently small.

Comment: Indeed, the secret lies in the $\approx$ symbol. But why is the approximation not always correct? Could you offer some more insight on that? The comment by Tom addresses this quite well I think.

Comment: The approximation is not always correct because it's an approximation; in mathematics, an approximation has a specific set of criteria which define when the expression is true. If it were always true, it would be an equality.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer to be so detailed and enlightening. I really appreciate your help!