# When are very small learning rates useful?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent, stochastic-gradient-descent

I just wondered if there are cases where small or very small learning rates in gradient descent based optimization are useful?

A large learning rate allows the model to explore a much larger portion of the parameter space. Small learning rates, on the other hand, can take the model a long time before it converges.

In which cases are small learning rates particularly useful?

Comment: If the learning rate is "too large," then the optimization can diverge. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/364360/how-can-change-in-cost-function-be-positive/364366#364366 A learning rate that is "small" in absolute terms might be the largest values that doesn't exhibit instability.

Comment: @Sycorax is right. Some food for thought is that [Smith 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00489) suggests that increasing the batch size is preferable to decaying the learning rate, but perhaps increasing the batch size isn't feasible in situations where decreasing the learning rate (either a priori or via decay) is possible.